# HttpContext.Current is null after Azure AD authentication success

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, openid-connect, httpcontext

Question: **What could be causing `HttpContext.Current` to be null only sometimes?**

Question: **Is `HttpContext.Current` initialized after `PrincipalService.OnAzureAuthenticationSuccess` is called? If so, why only sometiems?**

**Description**

What happens is quite often a user will click sign-in and `HttpContext.Current` will be null causing the cookie to be never set. Which redirects them back to the home-page and since the cookie wasn't set they click sign-in again and again and again. Sometimes it'll decide to let the cookie be set after 2 or 3 clicks other times it won't do it without clearing cookies or logging out of another Azure AD account (e.g. Our sharepoint server uses Azure AD).

These things seem so odd to me and I haven't been able to pin down what the cause is despite hours of research into it.

**Azure Config**

```
public static void ConfigureAzure(IAppBuilder app)
{
    // COOKIES: Tells it to use cookies for authentication.
    app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
    {
        // CUSTOMIZE: This is where you would adjust cookie experiation and things of that nature.
        SlidingExpiration = true,
        ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(CookieDurationInHours)
    });

    //https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect/
    // OPEN-ID: Handle OpenID stuff.
    var notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
    {
        AuthenticationFailed = PrincipalService.OnAzureAuthenticationFailure,
        // REFERENCE: https://russellyoung.net/2015/09/05/mvc-role-based-authorization-with-azure-active-directory-aad/
        AuthorizationCodeReceived = PrincipalService.OnAzureAuthenticationSuccess
    };
    var options = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions()
    {
        ClientId = ClientID,
        Authority = Authority,
        PostLogoutRedirectUri = PostLogoutRedirectUri,
        Notifications = notifications
    };
    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(options);
}
```

**On Azure Success**

```
/// <summary>
/// Stores the proper identity cookie (doesn't have customer permissions yet).
/// </summary>
public static Task OnAzureAuthenticationSuccess(AuthorizationCodeReceivedNotification context)
{
    var success = false;
    var username = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.Name;
    try
    {
        success = StoreCookie(username);
    }
    catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
    {
        var errors = ex.EntityValidationErrors.FirstOrDefault()?.ValidationErrors.FirstOrDefault()?.ErrorMessage;
        Logger.Log(Level.Error, "An error occurred while storing authentication cookie.", ex);
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.Log(Level.Error, "An error occurred while storing authentication cookie.", ex);
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    if (success)
    {
        Logger.Log(Level.Cookie, "Login Complete. Cookie stored successfully. Username: '" + username + "'.");
    }
    return Task.FromResult(0);
}
```

**Store Cookie**

```
/// <summary>
/// Creates and stores a forms authentication cookie for the user.
/// </summary>
private static bool StoreCookie(string username, bool rememberMe = false)
{
    var azureUsers = new AzureUserRepository(new AuthenticationEntities());
    var user = azureUsers.Get(u => u.Username == username);
    if (user == null)
    {
        Logger.Log(Level.Cookie, "User '" + username + "' not found.");
        throw new NullReferenceException();
    }

    // Clear any old existing cookies.
    if (HttpContext.Current == null)
    {
        // HERE: This is where it is null (again, only sometimes).
        Logger.Log(Level.Debug, "HttpContext is null.");
        return false;
    }
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request == null)
    {
        Logger.Log(Level.Debug, "HttpContext.Current.Request is null.");
        return false;
    }
    if (HttpContext.Current == null && HttpContext.Current.Response != null)
    {
        Logger.Log(Level.Debug, "HttpContext.Current.Response is null.");
        return false;
    }

    HttpContext.Current.Request.RemoveFormsAuthCookie();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.RemoveFormsAuthCookie();

    // Create the principal from the user object.
    var principal = new PrincipalModel(user);

    // Create and store the cookie in the response.
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddFormsAuthCookie(
        username: user.Username,
        userData: principal.SerializeUserData(),
        isPersistent: true
    );
    return true;
}
```

**AccountController**

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public void SignIn()
{
    if (Request.IsAuthenticated) { return; }

    HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(
        new AuthenticationProperties() { RedirectUri = "/" }, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType
    );

    Logger.Log(Level.Info, "Sign-In clicked.");
}

public void SignOut()
{
    if (!Request.IsAuthenticated) { return; }

    // SIGN OUT:
    HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(
        OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType
    );

    Logger.Log(Level.Info, "Sign-out clicked.");

    // COOKIE: Remove the cookie.
    var cookie = Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
    cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1); // DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1);
    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
}
```

Comment: Since you mentioned that the issue was not able to reproduced every time. Suspect it maybe caused by the code. To narrow down this issue, I suggest that you remove all the code except the code relative to the authentication. I am testing this issue use the sample [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect.git). And add the custom code like `AuthorizationCodeReceived = (notification) => {var a = HttpContext.Current;return Task.FromResult(0);}`

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your problem. I have two applications that use Azure AD authentication. I stepped through the `AuthorizationCodeReceived`  handler a number of times, and in all cases `HttpContext.Current` was not null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, so it turns out I was being a big dummy and doing things the hard way. I don't 100% fully understand why it was null but I did find a much simpler way around the issue.

1. Started by removing the code related to me creating my own cookie (i.e. `AuthorizationCodeReceived = PrincipalService.OnAzureAuthenticationSuccess`).

What happened was I realized that Azure AD was creating its own principal and cookie via the `app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());` This realization happened thanks to the git hub project that Fei Xue linked.

2. After that I switched my custom principal to create based on the 'built-in' cookie instead of the cookie I was creating (which was only getting created half of the time due to `HttpContext.Current` being `null`).

Now that the custom principal creation wasn't dependent on `HttpContext.Current` I didn't have a sign-in loop happening at all because the principal and cookie both exist.

Thanks a ton to Fei Xue!

Comment: Hi, did you solve the issue by removing your custom cookie creator?